# Dynamically changing View in AngularJS UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a walkthrough in my app which comprises 4 pages. I decided to make the Walkthrough a single state with multiple views to represent each of the 4 pages.

In my html I define a div as a ui-view pointed to the current view, which my controller then changes around as necessary.

The problem is, when I update $scope.currentView to 'general' it does not change what's actually seen on the screen! If I manually change it to 'general' in my _init function it does show the general page, but I cannot make it change based on a button click.

HTML:

```
<div ui-view="{{currentView}}@walkthrough"></div>
```

Controller:

```
var _init = function () {
    $scope.currentView = 'welcome';
};
_init();

$scope.setView = function (view) {
    $scope.currentView = view;
};
```

My state definition:

```
.state('walkthrough', {
    url: '/walkthrough',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'app/walkthrough/walkthrough.html',
            controller: 'walkthroughController'
        },
        'welcome@walkthrough': {
            templateUrl: 'app/walkthrough/welcome.html'
        },
        'general@walkthrough': {
            template: 'general'
        }
    }
})
```

And the button to update the view:

```
<img class="start-button center-block" ng-click="setView('general')" />
```

---

**Update 1**

I have tried the following to solve, none of which worked:

1. Changing currentView to a getter function getCurrentView() which returns the currentView. Same behavior.
2. Wrapping the currentView setter in a $scope.$apply. Get the $apply already in progress error
3. Wrapping the currentView setter in a $timeout. Same behavior

**Update 2**

I added a `<pre>` section which calls the identical code as in the ui-view, `{{currentView}}@walkthrough`. It shows the correct view, even though the page itself doesn't update the show the new view.

**Update 3**

I have tried every combination of how to programmatically set the view but nothing I've tried has worked. Whether I use a server to grab the view, function, straight up $scope variable, nothing. The variable itself is correct, but the view just won't change when I change the variable.

The strange part is it works once when I set the value of the currentView in my init() function. It works if I change the value to one of the next views in the code itself ($scope.currentView = 'general' <- this shows the general page), but not if I make a button click change the currentView to 'general'.

I've tried all manner of $scope.$applys, $digests, and $timeouts. Nothing I do will get the view itself to update. The only thing left is to make it into a bunch of divs with ng-show/hide which is really ugly and a pain to manage, and the reason I wanted to use views in the first place.

**Update 4**

Still no progress, regardless of what I try... I thought some weird combination of wrapping the variable change in a $timeout might prove useful but alas, nothing. My last thought was to change all of these to their own independent states, but then I'll end up with a bunch of duplicated code which is obviously not good. I use almost the same type of change in other section of my app (to change states though, not views), and it works perfectly. I cannot figure out why I can't change the view dynamically. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update 5**

Had some home after user's comment below but it has lead nowhere. I have tried to call all manner of $state changes to refresh the view but nothing has worked. I tried all of the follow, none of which had any impact on the page:

```
$state.reload();
$state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true });
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code for how the view ID is being passed to `setView` on click?

Comment: @Aweary <img class="start-button center-block" ng-click="setView('general')" />

Comment: @Aweary I trued using ng-click="currentView='general'" but that doesn't change the view at all (even when looking at debug vals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved this by just making every walkthrough page its own inherited state from parent walkthrough, each with the single view. Probably not the best method but I don't want to waste more time on this.

I would still love a method to just use nested views and navigate that way, since it'll be easier to add more in the future with that method without bloating my stateProvider.

```
        .state('walkthrough', {
            url: '/walkthrough',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/walkthrough/walkthrough.html',
                    controller: 'walkthroughController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('walkthrough.welcome', {
            url: '/welcome',
            views: {
                'walkthrough.welcome@walkthrough': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/walkthrough/welcome.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('walkthrough.general', {
            url: '/general',
            views: {
                'walkthrough.general@walkthrough': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/walkthrough/general.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('walkthrough.business', {
            url: '/business',
            views: {
                'walkthrough.business@walkthrough': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/walkthrough/business.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('walkthrough.friends', {
            url: '/friends',
            views: {
                'walkthrough.friends@walkthrough': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/walkthrough/friends.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

Now I can easily navigate between by using

```
<img ui-sref="walkthrough.general" />
```

Answer (score 3):

While the ui-view directive will take an interpolated value (`{{ something }}`) for the view name, it doesn't actually watch this for changes. Instead, view updates are only triggered by the `$stateChangeSuccess` and `$viewContentLoading` events. This is why you can observe it working the first time and only the first time.

You can verify this by looking at the linking function for the `$ViewDirective` in ui-router's source code: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/viewDirective.js.

This means that your `setView` function needs to call `$state.go`to trigger a state change, rather than just setting a property on scope. As pe the usual state change process, this will eventually result in a `$stateChangeSuccess` event being broadcast.

Comment: Thanks but this did not work. I am not actually changing state...only changing view. I tried to call a $state.go('walkthrough') anyway but this did not do anything, which I had expected since it was my current state anyway.

Comment: that was the point - to "change the view", you must do a state change. However, if you are already in the walkthrough state and call $state.go('walkthrough'), the router won't reload the state unless you specifically tell it to (reload: true).

Comment: I had reload: true (as you can see in Update 5 in my post) but it still was not working. I ended up just reworking that whole section so now each page is it's on child state of the parent 'walkthrough', working pretty well.