# Angular routing ui-view inside another ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Conception overview:

We have two tabs on index html. There we routing those tabs like that:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

On a second tab we have a selector, that switch tab's content in another ui-view like that:

```
<div ui-view="{{vm.currentView}}"></div>
```

where vm.currentView is a name of routing state ('book1' and etc.).

```
 .state('tab2', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'tab2.html',
        controller: 'Tab2Controller',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .state('tab2.content', {
        url: '/tab2',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'tab2.html'
            },
            'book1@tab2': {
                templateUrl: 'tab2-book1.html'
            },
            'book2@tab2': {
                templateUrl: 'tab2-book2.html'
            },
            'book3@tab2': {
                templateUrl: 'tab2-book3.html'
            },
            'book4@tab2': {
                templateUrl: 'tab2-book4.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

Everything is fine, except one thing: data content and name of a view is changing, but a template content isn't.

I resolved it by another way (based on exclude 'ui-view inside another ui-view' conception and separate views in states). But i still want to know: "How to do this with using 'ui-view inside ui-view' conception?"

[Here's a Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/RLzAh3D8aunOpKfFVcVa?p=preview)

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796707/dynamically-changing-view-in-angularjs-ui-router) could be useful.

Comment: Same results. ui-veiw can provide a template only once.

Comment: It doesn't, it just reads the name only when the state changes.

Comment: exactly.  last thing that will must to resolve it's how to transmit index of template.

Comment: That's means exclude 'ui-view in ui-view' conception. Yeah, I used ng-include in one of answer (i made directive that's provide templates, looks like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/y24z7H?p=preview)). I just want to know is it possible to make 'ui-view inside ui-view' conception or not? And it seems as not.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Its possible to make 'ui-view inside another ui-view'.

Lets say you have an **index.html**

```
<div ui-view="content"></div>
```

and state provider is like this :-

```
$stateProvider
   .state('books', {
        parent: 'pages',
        url: '/books',                   
        views: {
            'content@': {
                 templateUrl: 'books.html',
                 controller: 'BooksController'
             }
        }
   })
```

In books.html you have some links and another ui-view (nested ui-view). On click of links populate the nested ui-view.

**books.html**

```
<div>
     <a ui-sref="book1"></a>
     <a ui-sref="book2"></a>
     <a ui-sref="book3"></a>
</div>
<!-- nested ui-view -->
<div ui-view="bookDetails"></div>
```

now state provider is :-

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('books', {
        parent: 'pages',
        url: '/books',                   
        views: {
            'content@': {
                 templateUrl: 'books.html',
                 controller: 'BooksController'
             }
        }
    })
    .state('book1', {
        parent: 'books',                  
        views: {
            'bookDetails@books': {
                 templateUrl: 'book1.html',
                 controller: 'BookOneController'
             }
        }
    })
    .state('book2', {
        parent: 'books',                 
        views: {
            'bookDetails@books': {
                 templateUrl: 'book2.html',
                 controller: 'BookTwoController'
             }
        }
    })
    .state('book3', {
        parent: 'books',                
        views: {
            'bookDetails@books': {
                 templateUrl: 'book3.html',
                 controller: 'BookThreeController'
             }
        }
    })
```

**bookDetails@books** :- populate 'bookDetails' ui-view in 'books' state or we can say that find 'bookDetails' ui-view inside 'books' state and populate it with 'views' object.

Comment: So, that's a cool answer. 
Named ui-view at root. How i can't see that earlier.. excelent..
I make a plnkr. [Here is](http://plnkr.co/edit/y24z7H?p=preview)
PS: sry for waiting..

Answer (score 0):

As i explained earlier i just want to make 'ui-view inside another ui-view', but it seems impossible. I found two ways to resolve this "bug"(?).

**First way: Exclude 'ui-view inside another ui-view' and use 'ng-include'**

Simplest variant with minimal change of code. As you see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/y24z7H?p=preview), i replaced

```
 <div ui-view="{{vm.currentView}}"></div>
```

with

```
 <ng-include src="vm.getTemplateUrl(vm.selectedBook.id)"/>
```

and add function to controller, thats switch templates:

```
function getTemplateUrl(id) {
            switch (id) {
                case 0:
                    return 'tab2-book1.html';
                case 1:
                    return 'tab2-book2.html';
                case 2:
                    return 'tab2-book3.html';
                case 3:
                    return 'tab2-book4.html';
                default:
                    return 'tab2-book4.html';
            }
        }
```

**Second way: Formally save 'ui-view inside another ui-view' and separate views by states**

And as you see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zg15go?p=preview), formally i save 'ui-view inside ui-view', but in fact i just fully replace single ui-view by template from another single ui-view (can't set second ui-view by name).

```
$urlRouterProvider
        .when('/tab2', '/tab2/book4');

    $stateProvider
        .state('tab2', {
            url: '/tab2',
            templateUrl: 'tab2.html'
        })
        .state('tab2.book1', {
            url: '/book1',
            params: {
                id: 0
            },
            templateUrl: 'tab2-book1.html',
            controller: 'Tab2Controller',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('tab2.book2', {
            url: '/book2',
            params: {
                id: 1
            },
            templateUrl: 'tab2-book2.html',
            controller: 'Tab2Controller',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('tab2.book3', {
            url: '/book3',
            params: {
                id: 2
            },
            templateUrl: 'tab2-book3.html',
            controller: 'Tab2Controller',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('tab2.book4', {
            url: '/book4',
            params: {
                id: 3
            },
            templateUrl: 'tab2-book4.html',
            controller: 'Tab2Controller',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });
```

Where content of tab2.html is:

```
<ui-view class="page-container"></ui-view>
```

When selector changed i call ***vm.changeHandbook(vm.selectedBook)*** to switch templates:

```
function changeHandbook(ref) {
            $state.go(ref.value);
        }
```

This is most weird and difficult way, but in the end we get more cleaner code.